# How correctly detect device is tablet or phone

Tags: java, android

I can detect device type from attrs resources:

```
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>

// xlarge and sw600dp = tablet
// normal = phone

if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
    // is tablet
}
```

But some smaller tablets are detected as phones.

Comment: What is the technical definition of "tablet"?

Comment: I think it is better to check the model of your device rather than the screen size.

Comment: Unless you're trying to do telephony, what's the difference? If, for UI display purposes, Android differentiates devices by screen size, what are you hoping to gain by creating the distinction between phone and tablet?

Comment: In my solution problem is in device: 10,5" 1920x1200 px, detect as phones...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use TelephonyManager class.

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (Objects.requireNonNull(manager).getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){
     //Tablet
} 
else{
     //Mobile Device
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but some tablets with sim cards not have telephony services?